# Can I prove a function is continuous by looking at the domain?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I came across the following question in a calculus book: For the function $$f(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ show that it is continuous on the interval $$-1≤x≤1$$ The solution in the book showed that the one sided limits were equivalent to f(x) at the points x= -1 and 1. It also showed that there exists a limit at the point c that is equal to f(c). They demonstrated this by showing that the left and right hand limits are equivalent at c. $$-1<c<1$$ My question is, why do you need to use limits to determine that this function is continuous from $$-1≤x≤1$$ Can't you just say that the domain of this function is $$-1≤x≤1$$ and therefore it is continuous?

Comment: By your logic, every function is continuous on its domain? Where did you prove continuity in your last sentence?

Comment: Please look up the definition of continuous.

Comment: I can see from the function that it would have no asymptotes, holes, or jump discontinuities. Had it been an absolute value function or something else I agree that this would not be an effective strategy. But for a function this simple can the domain not just be analyzed?

Comment: The limits are equal, not "equivalent". Being able to "see" is never a proof.

Comment: Indeed, the function is "obviously" continuous; but the point of the example is to get familiar with the definition.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of functions that are defined on an interval but discontinuous on it.  Consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x-5 & -1 \le x < 0 \\
x+2 & 0 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$
The domain of this function is $[-1,1]$ but it is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are essentially using circular logic and only picturing continuous functions. A function can literally have any values it wants on its domain and be perfectly valid. For an extreme example, consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 1\text{,}\hfill &\text{if }x\text{ is rational;}\\
 0\text{,}\hfill &\text{if }x\text{ is irrational.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ has a natural domain of the entire real line, but has a discontinuity on every interval.